# running two powershell commandlets into a single command

Tags: powershell

I require file properties and its MD5 hash piped into a csv file, using two different commandlets for this purpose.
 Can I combine both into a single command or maybe a snippet and get the desired output?

I'm using the following to get hash of the desired file aswell as file properties

```
Get-FileHash C:\Windows\System32\drivers\1394bus.sys Algorithm SHA512 | Format-List 

Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32\drivers\1394bus.sys | Get-ItemProperty | Select VersionInfo | Format-List *
```

I'm basically new to this so any tips would be helpful!

Comment: `SHA12` should be `SHA512` or `SHA1` no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse the `Path` property from the output of `Get-FileHash` in a calculated property, like so:

```
Get-FileHash C:\Windows\System32\drivers\1394bus.sys -Algorithm SHA1 |Select *,@{Label='VersionInfo';Expression={(Get-Item $_.Path).VersionInfo}} |Format-List
```

Comment: Hi, that was a ton of help thanx!

Comment: Also, can I output different fields from versioninfo into the excel sheet instead of getting it all in a single column like im getting now?